# Proving inequality involving convex combination

Tags: inequality

What are the steps in proving this following inequality: for $p,q \in [0,1]$:
$$
p \log \frac{p}{q}+(1-p) \log \frac{1-p}{1-q} \ge 2(p-q)^2
$$
I'm just looking for an outline of the approach to tackle this sort of problem.

Comment: Find $f_p, f_q$ and solve $f_p=0=f_q$ for critical values and take it from there.

Comment: I'll work on it tomorrow morning. Its late now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider the function $$F=p \log \big(\frac{p}{q}\big)+(1-p) \log \big(\frac{1-p}{1-q}\big) -2(p-q)^2$$ and compute its derivative $$F'_p=-\log \left(\frac{1-p}{1-q}\right)+\log \left(\frac{p}{q}\right)-4 (p-q)$$ $$F'_q=\frac{1-p}{1-q}-\frac{p}{q}+4 (p-q)$$ $F'_q=0$ shows that $p=q$ and, if this is satisfied, then $F'_p=0$ and, for $p=q$, $F=0$.

Now, look at what happens if $p=q+\epsilon$. By Taylor, you would find that $$F\approx \frac{(1-2 q)^2}{2 (1-q) q} \epsilon^2$$ So, $p=q$ corresponds to a minimum of the function.